RegionOfInterest in VisionKit
I'm looking for an example of how to use RegionOfInterest when scanning for barcodes with VisionKit.  I understand the concept of creating a CGRect with the region, but I can't find anywhere where the doc explains how to apply the region.

Thanks for the quick reply Ilia, but this seems to be implemented in Vision to handle images.  I'm trying to use VisionKit to read the barcode from the camera's view.

Step-by-Step Example

Import VisionKit: Make sure to import the necessary frameworks in your Swift file.

    import VisionKit
    import UIKit 


Set Up the Document Scanner: Create and configure a VNDocumentCameraViewController.

    class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, 
    VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set up your view, button, etc.
        let scanButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        scanButton.setTitle("Scan Document", for: .system)
        scanButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scanDocument), for: .touchUpInside)
        // Add button to view and set constraints or frame
    }

    @objc func scanDocument() {
        let documentCameraVC = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        documentCameraVC.delegate = self
        present(documentCameraVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


Implement the Delegate Method: Handle the results of the scanning session.

func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didScanDocuments scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
    // Assuming you're only dealing with the first scanned page
    let scannedImage = scan.imageOfPage(at: 0)
    // You can now process this image for barcode detection
    detectBarcodes(in: scannedImage)
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


Detect Barcodes with Region of Interest: Use Vision's barcode detection with a specified ROI.

func detectBarcodes(in image: UIImage) {
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return }

    // Specify the region of interest
    let roi = CGRect(x: 0.1 * ciImage.extent.width,
                     y: 0.1 * ciImage.extent.height,
                     width: 0.8 * ciImage.extent.width,
                     height: 0.8 * ciImage.extent.height)

    let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { (request, error) in
        if let results = request.results as? [VNBarcodeObservation] {
            for barcode in results {
                print("Found barcode: \(barcode.payloadStringValue ?? "No Value")")
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the region of interest on the request
    request.regionOfInterest = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(roi, Int(ciImage.extent.width), Int(ciImage.extent.height))

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: [:])
    do {
        try handler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform request: \(error)")
    }
}

Explanation of Key Components

Region of Interest (ROI): The roi is a CGRect that defines the area of the image you want to search for barcodes. In this example, we set it to the center 80% of the image.

VNImageRectForNormalizedRect: This function converts the normalized rectangle (with values between 0 and 1) into an absolute rectangle based on the image dimensions. This is crucial for correctly setting the ROI on your barcode detection request.

Delegate Methods: The VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate protocol is used to get the scanned images, which are then processed to detect barcodes.


Additional Notes

Ensure that you handle permissions for camera usage in your app's Info.plist by adding NSCameraUsageDescription.

Depending on your requirements, you may want to adjust the region of interest dynamically based on user input or other conditions.



It's simpler than I thought to apply the regionOfInterest.  I just had to add viewController.regionOfInterest = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
in the override func viewDidLoad() function.  Thanks again Ilia for getting me to think differently about it.
